# Use Browser cookies with HttpClient in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, dotnet-httpclient

I'm starting a Silverlight 5 control to add some dynamic funcionality to an ASP MVC 4 application.

I'd like the Silverlight control to use browser's cookies when making http requests, so I can share the ASP MVC application's authentication.

I decided to use the recently released [portable `HttpClient` library](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek13PortableHttpClientMakesPortableLibrariesMoreUseful.aspx) to make the http requests, because it's new, supports Task based asynchronous calls and I already have a WPF desktop client which uses it, so I can reuse my knowledge.

**It appears, however, there is no easy way to make the `HttpClient` use the browser's cookies.**

My first attempt was to use `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix` and specify `WeRequestCreator.BrowserHttp` for "http" calls. It appears, however, HttpClient does not use WebRequest underline, or does not care to the `RegisterPrefix`. Using VisualStudio, I can see that `WebRequest` has a private static field called `portableWebRequestCreator`, and I wondered if it was intended to be used by portable Silverlight 5 libraries, as `HttpClient`. However, even if it did, I cannot change the instance, because it is not exposed and Silverlight does not allow private member reflection.

My next attempt will be to get the current browser cookies with `HtmlPage.Document.Cookies`, convert them into a CookieContainer, use it with HttpClient, convert the CookieContainer back to a string and update the browser cookies on every call.
It however looks like an overkill.